# Visual studio stuck installing and it gives up

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

This is the error log

```
enter code here
```

https://pastebin.com/pDy8H4sW

I have been googling solutions and no luck. Tried uninstalling all visual studio related folders, and reinstalling with admin privileges.
I am installing only the visual studio core , and the visual studio for unity workloads. The bottom bar under download won't get past zero.

I want to install visual studio so I can use it with Unity instead of monodevelop, but no luck after endless tries. I cant post on the visual studio community group because I would need to access it from the program that Im unable to install.

I know there are similar questions but none of those solutions seems to apply to my problem, plus my error log is different . Thank you for your help.

Comment: SO is a Programming Q&A site, not for general software issues. Instead this type of question is more for https://superuser.com.

Comment: I will use that forum thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says another installation already in progress, it sometimes does that when windows is installing updates, make sure that there is no windows update going on, restart your pc and try again.

Comment: thank you , how can I make sure there is no updates going on? what to look for on the windows task manager

Comment: Go to settings->updates, and make sure nothing is going on there, or restart your pc it should stop the update!

Comment: ok so I needed updates, Ill install them and try again. If it works Ill mark your answer as solved thank you

Comment: yep it was that after updating windows, the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

For the googlers, I was able to get past this by finding vs_installerservice.exe (or relevant installer exe) in task manager and changing the affinity to use different cores after it gets stuck.  This seems to free up whatever process is hanging and continue on.